# Android Change background color of single item in NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview

How can I change the background color of a single item in Navigation view, even if it is not selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create menu class :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_targets"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_target"
    android:title="Targets" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_testing"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_testing"
    android:title="Testing" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_course_work"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_course_work"
    android:title="Course Work" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_schedule"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_schedule"
    android:title="Schedule" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_profile"
    android:title="Profile" />
```

now in activity class :

```
    MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextAppearance), 0, s.length(), 0);
      //for single item 
     if (menuItem.getItemId()==R.id.nav_targets){
              menuItem.setTitle(s);   
            }
```

res / values / styles.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">text_size</item>
</style>
```

This will set the single item color and textsize.
Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this in navigation view:

```
app:itemIconTint="your color"
```